# Stacked modal bootstrap dialogs make scrolling back screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open multiple bootstrap modals over the another modal dialog.
But problem is that when I close the second modal by clicking outside of the modal background page starts scrolling.
I don't want that.

Here is HTML code,

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" data-modal-index="1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
             <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal-2">Launch Modal 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


    <div class="modal fade" id="test-modal-2" data-modal-index="2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal-3">Launch Modal 3</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here's the fiddle link,
https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');` to `hide.bs.modal` function

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    var $dialog = $(this);  
    var previousDialog = $dialog.data('previous-dialog');
    if (previousDialog){
        previousDialog.removeClass('aside');
        $dialog.data('previous-dialog', undefined);
    }
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/2/)

Note: If, above solution disable body scroll after closing all modals, to enable body scroll, we can listen to `hide.bs.modal` event on modal 1. and get back the scroll bar with following script.

```
$('#test-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/3/)

**More Elegant Solution**

As you have `data-modal-index` in HTML here `<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" data-modal-index="1">`
create a `var` in `hide.bs.modal` event

```
var Dialogindex = $dialog.data('modal-index');
```

and simple check with `if / else` the modals and enable and disable the scroll

```
if(Dialogindex==1){
    $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
} else {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
}
```

Script will be

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    var $dialog = $(this);
    var previousDialog = $dialog.data('previous-dialog');
    var Dialogindex = $dialog.data('modal-index');
    if (previousDialog) {
        previousDialog.removeClass('aside');
        $dialog.data('previous-dialog', undefined);

    }
    if(Dialogindex==1){
        $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
    } else {
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/4/)

**If modal get stuck**

[First Modal Stuck if 2nd modal opened and closed](https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/5/)

OP pointed out that if first modal height is more then the visible page height, and after closing 2nd, 3rd and 4th modal, the first modal get stuck, reason (may be) a bug in twitter bootstrap where it seems to remove the `modal-open` class from the body of first modal if 2 or more then 2 modals were open.

So solution in this case is

- Check whether parent modal is opened after child modal close
- Of open mean length is 1 then add `modal-open` class to body of the page

  ```
  if ($('.modal:visible').length) { 
      $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
  ```

Also changed bs hidden event from `hide.bs.modal` to `hidden.bs.modal` and removed true condition `if(Dialogindex==1)` and changed it to `if(Dialogindex)`

Script will be

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    var $dialog = $(this);
    var previousDialog = $dialog.data('previous-dialog');
    var Dialogindex = $dialog.data('modal-index');
    if (previousDialog) {
       previousDialog.removeClass('aside');
        $dialog.data('previous-dialog', undefined);

    }
    if(Dialogindex){
        if ($('.modal:visible').length) { 
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }
        $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
   } else {
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/6/)

Comment: you are welcome, edited the answer, incase the body scroll remain disabled after closing the first modal

Comment: what is "#test-modal" here?

Comment: it's the `id` of first modal, `<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" data-modal-index="1">`

Comment: if you open this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/2/ and check there is body scroll but after open and closing all modals, the scroll will not appear and page will not be scroll-able but if you check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/3/ open n close all modals, but when closing the first modal scroll will appear on body and page is scroll-able

Comment: that's not working for me..it's freezing the first modal if it has more lines(scroll)...https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/3/

Comment: if you try to add add line breaks in first div and open second div and then close that div and come back to div with line breaks it gets stucked...see this https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/4/

Comment: can you update the issue in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/4/, save it and post here

Comment: made some changes, see if this fix the issue where modal stuck https://jsfiddle.net/cLwj6jgw/6/

Comment: first changed the hidden event from `$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {` to `$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {` then changed this condition `if(Dialogindex){`  from `if(Dialogindex==1){` and last i put another condition where checking the if the all other modal closed and first one left open `if ($('.modal:visible').length) {$('body').addClass('modal-open'); }` and added it's default class so it won't get stuck